# How to generate a graph and visualize it from a TensorFlow code using google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, writer

I'm learning TensorFlow, and now when I tried to generate graphs in google colab with the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.add(2, 2, name='add')
b = tf.multiply(a, 3, name ='mult1')
c = tf.multiply(b, a, name='mult2')

print(c.numpy())

tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()

writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('C:\Users\LUCINALDO\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\Deep Learning\Grafos')
a = tf.add(2, 2, name='add')
b = tf.multiply(a, 3, name ='mult1')
c = tf.multiply(b, a, name='mult2')
writer.close()
```

I am shown the following error message

```
File "<ipython-input-20-a289120d76db>", line 11
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('C:\Users\LUCINALDO\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\Deep Learning\Grafos')
                                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How to save graph files in a computer folder(or in drive) using google colab?

Comment: Have you researched this error ? Doesn't the 'Files' icon on the left side in the notebook show a list of files ? Are you trying to save there ? It is not related to tensorflow at all.

Comment: I researched the error, but I couldn't find solutions to my problem, there it shows a directory path, I'm trying to save the file in the "Grafos" directory 

I tried to put two backslashes or put a normal slash, like:
C: \\ Users \\ LUCINALDO \\ Desktop \\ xampp \\ htdocs \\ Deep Learning \\ Grafos
or
C: / Users / LUCINALDO / Desktop / xampp / htdocs / Deep Learning / Grafos

It doesn't give an error like that, but it also doesn't save a file with the visible graph. My question is: how to do this using google colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to save it as you see.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.add(2, 2, name='add')
b = tf.multiply(a, 3, name ='mult1')
c = tf.multiply(b, a, name='mult2')

print(c.numpy())

tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()

writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('/test')
a = tf.add(2, 2, name='add')
b = tf.multiply(a, 3, name ='mult1')
c = tf.multiply(b, a, name='mult2')
writer.close()
```

[image]